# How to change the expression of the result of function `LinearSolve`

Tags: linear-algebra, output-formatting

I want to solve the following linear equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
x_{1}+3 x_{2}+x_{3} &=0 \\
2 x_{1}+6 x_{2}+3 x_{3}-2 x_{4} &=0 \\
-2 x_{1}-6 x_{2}-4 x_{4} &=0
\end{aligned}\right.$$

The form of the solution given in the textbook is as follows:

$$\boldsymbol{X}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-3 k_{1}-2 k_{2} \\
k_{1} & 2 k_{2} \\
k_{2}
\end{array}\right)=k_{1}\left(\begin{array}{r}
-3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right)+k_{2}\left(\begin{array}{r}
-2 \\
0 \\
2 \\
1
\end{array}\right), \quad k_{1}, k_{2} \text { are arbitrary constants }$$

```
Solve[{x1 + 3 x2 + x3 == 0, 
  2 x1 + 6 x2 + 3 x3 - 2 x4 == 0, -2 x1 - 6 x2 - 4 x4 == 0}, {x1, x2, 
  x3, x4}]
LinearSolve[{{1, 3, 1, 0}, {2, 6, 3, -2}, {-2, -6, 0, -4}}, {0, 0, 0}]
NullSpace[{{1, 3, 1, 0}, {2, 6, 3, -2}, {-2, -6, 0, -4}}]
```

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
x_{1}+x_{2}-2 x_{3}-x_{4}=& 4 \\
3 x_{1}-2 x_{2}-x_{3}+2 x_{4}=& 2 \\
5 x_{2}+7 x_{3}+3 x_{4}=-2 \\
2 x_{1}-3 x_{2}-5 x_{3}-x_{4}=& 4
\end{aligned}\right.$$

The form of the solution given in the textbook is as follows:

$$\boldsymbol{X}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)+k\left(\begin{array}{r}
-\frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{2}{3} \\
1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)+k_{1}\left(\begin{array}{r}
-2 \\
1 \\
-2 \\
3
\end{array}\right), \quad k, k_{1} \text { are arbitrary constants }$$

```
Solve[{{1, 1, -2, -1}, {3, -2, -1, 2}, {0, 5, 7, 
     3}, {2, -3, -5, -1}}.{x1, x2, x3, x4} == {4, 2, -2, 4}, {x1, x2, 
  x3, x4}]
LinearSolve[{{1, 1, -2, -1}, {3, -2, -1, 2}, {0, 5, 7, 
   3}, {2, -3, -5, -1}}, {4, 2, -2, 4}]
NullSpace[{{1, 1, -2, -1}, {3, -2, -1, 2}, {0, 5, 7, 
   3}, {2, -3, -5, -1}}]
```

But the solution form of the above code output is not the style of the textbook. How can we make the `LinearSolve` function output consistent with the result form of the textbook (arbitrary  constant can be replaced by `c`)?

**In addition,** I have another problem. To prove that two linear equations have the same solution, we need the row vectors of their augmented matrices to be equivalent to each other.

For example, to prove that the linear equations represented by the following two matrices have the same system of solutions, I need to remove the meaningless zero row vector at the end:

```
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 6}}]
```

I wonder if there's any more clever way to get rid of the meaningless zero row vector at the end of a matrix:

```
Select[RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 
    6}}], # 0 != # &]
```

[image]

*By the way, it's inconvenient to customize the display size of the inserted images.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might `Solve` over the integers (like `LinearSolve` does in this case) to avoid fractions:

```
solvec = {x1, x2, x3, x4} /.
    Solve[
     {{1,  1, -2, -1},
      {3, -2, -1,  2},
      {0,  5,  7,  3},
      {2, -3, -5, -1}
     }.{x1, x2, x3, x4} == {4, 2, -2, 4},
     {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers
     ] // Normal // First
```

> ```
> (*  {1 + 2 C[1], 1 - C[1], -1 + 2 C[1], -3 C[1]}  *)
> ```

Output formatting with `CoefficientArrays`:

```
vectorToColumnMatrix = Transpose@List[#] &;
columnMatrices = Transpose /@ List /@ Transpose[#] &;

Flatten@ MapThread[Apply]@ {
     {MatrixForm @* vectorToColumnMatrix, 
      Map[MatrixForm] @* columnMatrices},
     List /@ CoefficientArrays[solvec, Variables[solvec]]
     } . Prepend[Variables[solvec], 1] // Normal
```

[image]

One could add `GeneratedParameters -> k` to `Solve` and

```
k /: Format[k[n_]] := Subscript[k, n];
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple custom function to implement this requirement:

```
 linearSolve[mat_?MatrixQ, b_] := 
 Module[{m, n, L, k, generalsolution, specialsolution, 
   specialsolutionColumn},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[mat];
  L = Length[NullSpace[mat]];
  generalsolution = 
   MapThread[
    Defer[#1*MatrixForm[#2]] &, {Array["k" <> ToString[#] &, L], 
     Map[List[#]\[Transpose] &, NullSpace[mat]]}]; 
  specialsolution = LinearSolve[mat, b];
  specialsolutionColumn = {LinearSolve[mat, b]}\[Transpose];
  
  If[specialsolution.specialsolution == 0 || b.b == 0, 
   If[Length[generalsolution] != 1, 
    StandardForm[
     Defer @@ 
      MakeExpression[StringRiffle[generalsolution, "+"], 
       StandardForm]], StandardForm[Defer @@ First[generalsolution]]], 
   StandardForm[
    Defer @@ 
     MakeExpression[
      StringRiffle[
       PrependTo[generalsolution, MatrixForm[specialsolutionColumn]], 
       "+"], StandardForm]]]]

    linearSolve[{{1, 1, -2, -1}, {3, -2, -1, 2}, {0, 5, 7, 
       3}, {2, -3, -5, -1}}, {4, 2, -2, 4}]

    linearSolve[{{1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 0}, {-2, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 0}]

    linearSolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}]

    linearSolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}, {0, 0, 0}]
    
    {{1, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
       0}} /. {a__List, {0 ..} ..} -> {a}
```

I'd like to see other people do that in a more subtle way.